# Modulation signal getting distored when connecting demodulator

Tags: ltspice, modulation, demodulation, distortion

Good day Guys,

I have a question regarding output signals of a specific stage getting distorted when connecting the next stage. 
In my scenario, I am working on an AM modulator and demodulator of a 10kHz square wave with a carrier frequency of 850Khz, currently, my Modulation is working and producing a nice modulated signal.
Before implementing my demodulator I run my modulated signal through a Gain stage ( Operational Amplifier ) to amplify the modulated because of its low peak values that are influencing the accuracy of the Demodulator.
When I send the demodulated signal through the gain stage (without the gain stage output connected to the demodulator) I get a nice amplified signal.
However, my problem comes in when I connect my demodulator to the output of the Amplifier stage, the output from the Amplifier stage changes to a very weird looking signal. The modulated, amplified (without demodulator stage connected) and amplified (with demodulator stage connected) can be seen in the figure below,[image: Signals]

So my question is why does this distortion happen, and how can it be fixed?
I am terribly sorry if it is due to noobies mistake!

If have attached a screenshot of my Circuit below, [image: LtSpice Circuit]

Comment: Are you using LTSpice??? If so, do you a model for your diodes??? Or try right click and the pick new diode a select a diode that fits your application.

Comment: I did this, it, however, didn't have any effect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem seems to be in how you are powering your LT1468. You have powered as a single ended source since V4 is no way referenced to ground. Use 2 Voltage sources reference to ground, one positive or one negative. Additionally you can change your amplifier setup to work as a single-end mode.

Comment: I have accepted your answer because you answered first, however, @EnricBlanco your answer, that helped me. is the same as @Kvegaoro! Thank you very much, guys! I didn't realize that has such a massive influence, will remember this in future projects!

Answer (score 1):

You're biasing the OpAmp in a rather strange way. V+ should come from a +5V DC voltage source connected to ground. The same goes for V- and -5V to ground. Try this before anything else.

If after trying that it keeps not working work, try also the following in addition to it:

1. Reduce the voltage gain of the stage before the demodulator. If required, split your total gain of 1,000 in 2 or 3 stages, with the last one having less gain than the others.
2. Use +/-15V supply voltages.
3. Use another OpAmp, maybe a more general-purpose one.

Comment: Please see the comment on Kvegaoro's answer!